# How to create multiple aggregate which has different filters in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am new to MonogoDB  and my Data is a follows:

```
{Country :India, Gender:M, Salary :100, Name:Kathis  }
{Country :Gulf, Gender:F, Salary :100, Name:Harika }
{Country :USA, Gender:M, Salary :300, Name:ALllt  }
{Country :Afr, Gender:M, Salary :400, Name:Surya  }
```

Output should be:

```
{Total Count:4, "Count of Gender":1, "Count of Salary":2, "Count of Name":1}
```

Output Explanation:

- **Total Count:** Total Number of Country across all documents
- **Count of Gender:** Count gender only if it is 'F' (since there is only one Female, count is one).
- **Count of Salary:** Count Salary if  greater than 200, hence count is 2
- **Count of Name:** if it starts with 'A' Then count it

Things I have tried:

```
db.getCollection('Raw')..aggregate([
  {
    $facet: {
      "total Country": [{ $sum:1 }],
      "Count of Gender":[{$match:{"Gender":"F"}}]
       ........
    }
  }
])
```

Please let me know if this process is right or wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Please let me know if this process is right or wrong?

Yes that is also right approach but its up to number of documents in collection, there is a another approach below i have explained, you can test both and check performance using [explain()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.explain/index.html) state method,

You can use `$group` stage to count as per your conditions,

- `$group` by null
- get total count using $sum: 1
- get gender count, check condition if `Gender` is equal to F then sum 1
- get salary count, check condition if `Salary` greater than 200 then sum 1
- get name count, check regular expression match if `Name` start from "A" then sum 1

```
db.getCollection('Raw')..aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      totalCount: { $sum: 1 },
      genderCount: {
        $sum: { $cond: [{ $eq: ["$Gender", "F"] }, 1, 0] }
      },
      salaryCount: {
        $sum: { $cond: [{ $gt: ["$Salary", 200] }, 1, 0] }
      },
      nameCount: {
        $sum: { $cond: [{ $regexMatch: { input: "$Name", regex: "^A" } }, 1, 0] }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/29JWiuYY0Qr)